# Uploading files in Django using jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to upload multiple files for a blog post object, however, it seems that my Ajax form is not working properly and I cannot see the files uploading.

Since there is no post object at the time of creating the images, I am trying to upload the files then get them in my view and after saving the post I am trying to save those files by assigning the id of that post to them. Currently, my issue is it seems my files are not uploading and I cannot get them at all.

I am not getting any error and therefore, I cannot find an issue.

Below is my file upload and post create view:

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():    
            post = form.save(False)
            post.author = request.user
            #post.likes = None
            post.save()
            for image in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                instance = Images(post=Post.objects.get(post.id),image=image)
                instance.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            posts = Post.objects.all()
            posts = Post.objects.order_by('-last_edited')
            data['posts'] = render_to_string('home/posts/home_post.html',{'posts':posts},request=request)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = PostForm       
    context = {
    'form':form
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('home/posts/post_create.html',context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data) 

class PostImageUpload(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request):
        images = Images.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'home/posts/post_create.html', {'images':images} ) 

    def post(self, request):
        data = dict()
        form = ImageForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(False)
            image.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': image.file.name, 'url': image.file.url} 
        else:
            data['is_valid'] = False
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

This my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".js-upload-images").click(function () {
      $("#fileupload").click();
    });

    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
      change : function (e, data) {
        if(data.files.length >= 4){
            alert("Sorry, you can only upload up to 4 images")
            return false;
        }
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      sequentialUploads: true,  
      start: function (e)  { 
        $("#modal-progress").show();
      },
      stop: function (e) {  
        $("#modal-progress").hide();
      },
      progressall: function (e, data) {  
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        var strProgress = progress + "%";
        $(".progress-bar").css({"width": strProgress});
        $(".progress-bar").text(strProgress);
      },
      done: function (e, data) {
        if (data.result.is_valid) {
          $("#image_list tbody").prepend(
            "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
          )
        }
      }
    });
});
```

HTML Code

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/image_upload.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

<form method="POST" data-url="{% url 'home:post-create' %}" class="post-create-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" >Create a Post</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="my-3 mx-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mr-auto btn-primary js-upload-images">
                <span><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></span>
                </button>
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
                        style="display: none;"
                        data-url="{% url 'home:post-image-upload'  %}"
                        data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

                <table id="image_list" class="table table-bordered my-2">
                <tbody>
                    {% for image in images %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="{{ image.file.url }}">{{ image.file.name }}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The fileupload framework that I am using is working as well as I can see in the terminal Django is successfully completing the get request.

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly where the error is. You said `I am not getting any error and therefore, I cannot find an issue.` Does this mean your function in `views.py` runs fine? Are you confident about the implementation of it?

Comment: My post create view runs fine, I cannot see any issues in the terminal. I cannot say for certain if there is an issue with it or not. The only thing I am unsure of if the post_create view is getting the image objects correctly @azycrw4282

Comment: @ashes999 you mean you actually set a breakpoint inside the `post()` method of your view and execution halts at your breakpoint, proving that the view is running? Please step through your view in your debugger to actually check that the form is valid and saved.